# Как в XSLT отрезать первые 2 символа, если они равняются определенным символам?

Tags: xml, xslt

Подскажите, есть строка "XXQWERTY". Как мне отобразить строку без "XX", если эти символы в начале? 
"XXQWERTY" = "QWERTY"
"YZQWERTY" = "YZQWERTY"

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="starts-with(., 'XX')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 3)"/> 
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Функцией `starts-with` определяем, начинается ли значение с определённых символов. Если да - функцией `substring` получаем значение с указанной позиции. Если нет - берём значение целиком.